# jQuery: How to create a sticky sidebar within a parent container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys is it possible to make a sticky sidebar within a div container? I tried using position fixed but using fixed changed the elements position relative to the window. So I did some searching to find out if it was possible to do a fixed position relative to the parent div and basically all the answers were No.

After that I searched for another way to do this and I found nothing(maybe I'm really bad at searching). So that's why I am asking it here do you guys have an idea how I could make a sticky sidebar relative to its parent div instead of window?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: fiddle
    [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PttmhA/7ahsm/7/)

```
jQuery(function() { // document ready
        var sideBarTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top; // position top
        var sideBarLeft = $('#sidebar').offset().left //position left
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns scroll from top
            if(sideBarTop < windowTop) {
                $('#sidebar').css({position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: sideBarLeft});
            }
            else {
                $('#sidebar').css('position', 'static');
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or example code of what you currently have?

Comment: Giving the parent element position relative works for me, you just need to position your fixed element via margins and not via left,top,bottom,right

Comment: @justin Added the fiddle

Comment: @LJ_1102 The problem is I am using percentage for my widths

Comment: You can use margins with percentages as well, i cant see any problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` and with Jquery change the `top` property based on the scroll of the parent element like this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ 
   var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop()+30; 
   jQuery('#sidebar').css('top',windowTop);  
});
```

Check your Demo Fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/7ahsm/19/**.

In your example is almost the same as use `position:fixed` but check this another example: **http://jsfiddle.net/3CduR/**

Comment: @user3261212 np mate glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed will 'fix' the element relative to the viewport. What you need to do is make the parent element `position: relative` and the child element that is to be fixed relative to parent should be `position: absolute; left: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `position: absolute;`

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qw63j/